# MappingException: Could not determine type; Using @Embeddable and @Embedded

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

I am attempting to move a framework from hibernate3 to 4, this code worked in 3.  The framework uses Interfaces to break the tight coupling of classes.  Hence:

The Entity class is marked with @Entity and this instance uses and an instance of and @Embeddable defined as its interface, a very familiar pattern in Spring.

The code works fine in older versions of hibernate (V3), I am moving it to JPA2 and Hibernate 4

I realize that Hibernate would have a difficult time figuring out which implementation (concrete class) of the interface was being being mapped.  Hence I understand the error, however, it does work on older versions.

Is this due to hibernate templates and mapping classes in older versions that are abstracted away in JPA2 & H4.

Is the best approach to simply create concrete implementations of all the interface implementing classes and define the @embedded as a concrete class.

Thanks much in advance.

// the Entity class HibAttribute

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
// Define a unique constraint on item, namespace, and localname
@Table(name="attribute", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"itemid", "namespace", "localname"})})
// Define indexes on discriminator and key fields
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(
        appliesTo="attribute", 
        indexes={@Index(name="idx_attrtype", columnNames={"attributetype"}),
                 @Index(name="idx_attrname", columnNames={"localname"}),
                 @Index(name="idx_attrns", columnNames={"namespace"})})
@DiscriminatorColumn(
        name="attributetype",
        discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING,
        length=16)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)

public abstract class HibAttribute extends HibAuditableObject implements java.io.Serializable, Attribute {

    // Fields

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides( {
            @AttributeOverride(name="namespace", column = @Column(name="namespace", nullable = false, length=255) ),
            @AttributeOverride(name="localName", column = @Column(name="localname", nullable = false, length=255) )
    } )
    private QName qname;


//  The interface public interface QName {

    /**
     * Get local name
     * @return local name
     */
    public String getLocalName();

    /**
     * Set local name
     * @param localName local name
     */
    public void setLocalName(String localName);

    /**
     * Get namespace
     * @return namespace
     */
    public String getNamespace();

    /**
     * Set namespace
     * @param namespace namespace
     */
    public void setNamespace(String namespace);

    /**
     * Create copy of QName object.
     * @return copy of current QName object
     */
    public QName copy();

}

@Embeddable
public class HibQName implements QName {

    public static final String DEFAULT_NAMESPACE = "org.osaf.cosmo.default";

    private String namespace = null;
    private String localName = null;

    public HibQName() {}

    /**
     * Create new QName with specified namespace and local name.
     * @param namespace namespace
     * @param localName local name
     */
    public HibQName(String namespace, String localName) {
        this.namespace = namespace;
        this.localName = localName;
    }
```

// rest of class has been omitted ....... it is not needed to understand this issue.

The Stack trace:
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: org.timbre.model.QName, at table: attribute, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(attributes_KEY)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.IndexedCollection.validate(IndexedCollection.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1294)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1732)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
    ... 57 more

Comment: I'm a little confused, should QName interface have Embeddable annotation on it? Neither the interface nor the HibQName implementation has Embeddable annotation. Maybe there is just something wrong with your example since the first line of QName is commented out:  //  The interface public interface QName {

Comment: I forgot to take out that comment in fact the HibQName is declared embeddable and in the HibAttribute class it is declared as embedded.